# Textbox forecolor == "window" for non selected controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, textbox

I'm trying to do something with the textbox control, I want that all controls take the color "window" (which I already set to it in properties). It works but only for the current selected control, I want all controls with the "window" color all time.

How can I do this

Comment: Click and drag a selection rectangle to select more than one control in the designer.  Or hold down the shift key while clicking.

Comment: I want the default view of all controls to be the color selected.... not select all controls...

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have a variable of type color named window and you want to programmatically set all of the controls to that color.

```
foreach( Control myControl in this.Controls)
{
    myControl.BackColor = window;
}
```

That does the trick, assuming you've added the controls to the "Controls" collection in the form.

EDIT: Alternatively, if you want just the textboxes to change, you can always use this if statement around the assignment

```
if (myControl.GetType()==typeof(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox))
```

Comment: I believe he meant this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.window.aspx

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, I guess I was just giving a general answer.  He can always just do window=System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window or whatever color he wants.